# how to use ng-circle-progress src code in an angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, geometry

I'm using angular 6 and I want to use [`ng-circle-progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress). I implemented the circles but I want to change something that I think I should do it from the src code. there is a `units` and `title` options in the circles and I want them to get closer to each other. How can I do it?

**app.module.ts**

```
import {
  NgCircleProgressModule
} from 'ng-circle-progress';

imports: [
  CommonModule,
  RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutingModule),
  NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
    "units": "Liter",
    "outerStrokeLinecap": "butt"
  })
]
```

**home.component.html**

```
<circle-progress
    [percent]="65"
    [radius]="100"
    [outerStrokeWidth]="8"
    [innerStrokeWidth]="2"
    [outerStrokeColor]=tank.outerColor
    [innerStrokeColor]="'#e2e2e2'"
    [animation]="true"
    [animationDuration]="300"
    [space]="5"
    [showSubtitle]= "false"
    [showUnits]= "true"
    [unitsFontSize]= "15"
    [titleFontSize]= "45"
    [clockwise]= "false">
</circle-progress>
```

and this is the image of output. how can I control the space between `65` and `liter`?

[image]

Comment: You better to ask your issue in [ng-circle-progress githab page](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues)

Answer (score 0):

To control space between the outer and inner circles, tweak the 'space' option.
If you want to reduce the space between the circles, use negative values.

Something like this:

```
<circle-progress
    ..... //other options
    [space]="-5"
    ..... //other options
</circle-progress>
```

If you want to set a default for all the progress bars in the application, you can add this option in imports like this:

```
imports: [
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
        space = -5
      })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug.

Open the develop tools panel in your browser, can you see a white space on the right of the title?

[image]

You'd better post a issue.

https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues